# Custom Collection Issue

Tags: magento-1, collection

This is my query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* ,
  CONCAT (`main_table`.`name`, " (", count(*), "x)") as `total`
FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `main_table`
WHERE (`order_id` = '145375')
GROUP BY `main_table`.`name`
```

This is my collection right now:

```
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $row->getData('entity_id'));
```

I want to **add the concat condition and group by condition**. How can I do that ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, after your collection code add:

```
$orderItems->getSelect()->columns(array('total' => 'concat(name, " (", count(*), "x)")'));
$orderItems->getSelect()->group('name');
```

Comment: thx a lot !  it works